# Does $\{1,x,x^2....\}$ span $F(\mathbb R)$, where $F(\mathbb R)$ is the set of all functions $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**My Approach:**

I'm assuming that $\{1,x,x^2,\dots\}$ is $P(R)$, the set of all polynomials.

Suppose $\{1,x,x^2,\dots\}$ spans $F(R)$. Then by definition $F(R) = \text{span } P(R)$. However, $P(R)$ is a subspace of $F(R)$ and as a result, $P(R)$ can not span $F(R)$.

Sorry in advance if this is not the best proof/approach.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots\}$ is not the set of "all *poly*nomials": it's the set of *mono*mials.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he meant to say that $\text{span}(1,x,x^2,\dots)$ is the set of all polynomials.  (*note: formal power series which have an an infinite number of nonzero terms are not included in the span*)

Comment: Note that a vector space is a subspace of itself, so just saying $P(R)$ is a subspace of $F(R)$ does not mean that $P(R) \neq F(R)$.  And you need to prove the latter.

Comment: That isn't a proof; it's just a rewording of the original assertion.

Answer (score 2):

It would be simpler to note that, since each of the functions $1$, $x$, $x^2$, … is continuous, all the functions from the space that they span is continuous too. But there are discontinuous functions in $F(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: It is worth mentioning as well that it doesn't span the set of all continuous functions either.  For example, $e^x$ cannot be represented by a *finite* linear combination of terms from $\{1,x,x^2,\dots\}$ (*though it can be represented by an /infinite/ one*).

Answer (score 1):

> $P(\mathbb{R})$ is a subspace of $F(\mathbb{R})$

This line of reasoning screams two things to me.

- Firstly, a linguistic problem: "subspaces" don't have to be *proper* subspaces: that is, the two could still be equal. (For example, $F(\mathbb{R})$ is a subspace of $F(\mathbb{R})$ - it's the biggest one there is!)
- Secondly, a logical problem. Even if we replace "subspace" by "proper subspace": you've claimed that $P(\mathbb{R})$ is a proper subspace of $F(\mathbb{R})$, but how do you know that? The phrase "$P(\mathbb{R})$ is a subspace of $F(\mathbb{R})$" is actually just a *fancier way of saying* "$\{1, x, x^2,\dots\}$ does not span $F(\mathbb{R})$", rather than a proof of that statement.

There are many reasons why $P(\mathbb{R})$ is not all of $F(\mathbb{R})$. José above mentioned continuity, and so if you know what continuity is, you can use that. Another elementary reason, for instance, is the following. Take any nonzero $f\in P(\mathbb{R})$: then $f$ has only finitely many roots (in fact, if $f$ has degree $n$, then $f$ has at most $n$ roots, by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra). So it suffices to choose a nonzero element $g\in F(\mathbb{R})$ that has infinitely many roots, i.e. whose graph crosses the $x$-axis infinitely many times. But I'm sure you can think of a nonzero function that crosses the $x$-axis infinitely many times: take e.g. $g(x) = \sin(x)$. This shows that $\sin$ is not in $P(\mathbb{R})$.